# jQuery tablesorter - Hide specific table content from the sorter/filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I need to use https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/ for a project. Unfortunatly I'm a total js-neewbie and I think I'm at my limits with my english skills while looking for a solution in the docs:

I'm trying to create a table with a dropdown-filter. But this filter shouldn't extract the whole cells content, but only the first line - here's my example: http://kentzler.tv/sorter-example/

In the second column the dropdown should only show the citys, in the third it should only extract the event categories without the description. Maybe there's a simple way to assign a css-class to what is supposed to be extracted or what not, but I just can't find it :(

Would be great if somebody could help! Thanks in advance and greetings from germany,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to use is the [`filter_selectSource` widget option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource).

It will accept:

#### Function

```
filter_selectSource : function(table, column, onlyAvail) {
  // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
  var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
  // manipulate the array as desired, then return it
  return array;
}
```

#### Array

```
filter_selectSource : {
  ".model-number" : [ "abc", "def", "ghi", "xyz" ]
}
```

#### Object

```
filter_selectSource  : {
  0 : [
    { value : '/\\.js$/',            'data-class' : 'ui-icon-script',   text : 'javascript' },
    { value : '/\\.(jpg|png|gif)$/', 'data-class' : 'ui-icon-image',    text : 'Image' },
    // plain strings are also acceptable - the string is added to both the text & value attribute
    'foobar',
    { value : '.css',                'data-class' : 'ui-icon-note',     text : 'CSS' },
    { value : '.html',               'data-class' : 'ui-icon-document', text : 'HTML page' },
    { value : '/\\.(json|txt|md)$/', 'data-class' : 'ui-icon-help',     text : 'Misc' },
  ]
}
```

This is useful if using a third party plugin to create the select dropdown